# How to send response error code in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I would like to know how to send error code in promise as response in nodejs. Error in Promise Not sending any error in response object in NodeJS/Express

```
module.exports.providerData = function (reqUrl, query) {
  return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
    try {
      var validUrl = checkValidParamters(reqUrl, query);
      if(validUrl != true){
       throw new Error('failed');
      }
      else{
        sendcountry = countryjson.filter(function (send) {
          return send.country_name == param_sendcountry;
        })
        var provider_sendcncode = sendcountry[0].country_code;
        var receive = countryjson.filter(function (pr) {
          return pr.country_name == param_receivecountry;
        })
        var valid = true;
        var valid_obj = { validstatus: valid};
        resolve(valid_obj);
      }
    }
    catch (err) {
     reject(err);
    }
  });

}
```

in app.js

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  if (getcountries == null && getcurrencies == null && getproviders == null) {
            util.providerData(req.originalUrl, req.query).then(obj => {
              res.render("corridor.ejs");
            }).catch(err=>{
              res.status(401).send({ error : err.message });
            })
  }
  else {
    console.log('just return');
          util.providerData(req.originalUrl, req.query).then(obj => {
              res.render("corridor.ejs");
            }).catch(err=>{
              res.status(401).send({ error : err.message });
            })
  }
});
```

I need to catch the error response  `res.status(401).send({ error : err.message });` if export function is returning false/error

Comment: As far as I can see, the code seems alright and should work. Which part is failing?

Comment: @varunagarwal if the export function return validUrl  as false, i will catch the error as "Failed", in app.js it should res.status(401).send({ error : err.message }) , failing to send response status

Comment: Basically your client is not receiving the `401` error status on making the api call?

Comment: @varunagarwal yes

Comment: post `checkValidParamters()` code , also use debugger to find the issue or just `console.log(validUrl) ` to check what actually you are getting.

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam thanks for reply, i would like to catch the error, if validurl is false, am not able send response

Comment: try to using return. `return res.status(401).send({ error : err.message });`

Comment: @sowmiya what is your `checkValidParamters()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your promise doesn't resolve anything. to resolve, you just simple return your response.

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
   if (getcountries == null && getcurrencies == null && getproviders == null) {
        return util.providerData(req.originalUrl, req.query).then(obj => {
          return res.render("corridor.ejs");
        }).catch(err=>{
          return res.status(401).send({ error : err.message });
        })
  }
    else {
       console.log('just return');
       return util.providerData(req.originalUrl, req.query).then(obj => {
          return res.render("corridor.ejs");
        }).catch(err=>{
          return res.status(401).send({ error : err.message });
        })
  }
});
```